# Why justify-content: space-between; doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

Do you have any idea where did I make a mistake? Seems like space-between doesn't do its job. Should I add additional padding to fix it or use a different display method? I was following a tutorial, but sill can't figure out where is the problem. Would be grateful for any suggestions

[image]
should look like this
[image]
But it looks like this

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #013456;
  --accent-color: #fad405;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 81px;
  max-width: 1231px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Istok Web";
  text-align: right;
}
.header span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header-title {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .plane-ico {
  color: var(--accent-color);
}
.header-navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.header-navigation a {
  text-emphasis: none;
  margin-left: 29px;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .menu-ico,
.header .close-ico {
  display: none;
}

.header .close-ico {
  color: var(--accent-color);
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
      <h2 class="header-title">
        <span>Matt Ridd</span>
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-paper-plane plane-ico"></i>
        <nav id="header-navigation" class="header-navigation">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Books</a>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
          <a href="#">Home </a>
        </nav>
        <i onclick="toggleMenu('block')" class="fa fa-bars menu-ico"></i>
        <i
          onclick="toggleMenu('none')"
          id="close-ico"
          class="fa fa-times-circle close-ico"
        ></i>
      </h2>
    </header>
```

Comment: Your `.header` contains only _one_ child, the `h2` - so how do you expect distributing space "between" _one single_ element would work ...?

Comment: Also, FYI: Nesting `nav` into `h2` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving "header-title" `width: 100%;`, and shifting `justify-content: space-between;` from the "header" class to "header-title", furthermore "header-title" should be a div.

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/2rz0mp5o/)